# Knockout.js - making nested dynamic field values observable

Tags: knockout.js

I am dynamically creating sets of form fields using nested observable arrays in Knockout. I would like to be able to make the "allocation" fields observable so that I can add up the user data, and make sure it doesn't exceed 100%. See my JS fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/e984J/

The JS:

```
var initialData = [
    /* Sample data
        { prodName: "MSVR", splits: [
            { page: "Page Name", allocation: "10%"},
            { page: "Page Name", allocation: "20%"}]
    }*/
];

var ProductsModel = function(products) {
    var self = this;
    self.mmAllPages = ko.observableArray(['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3']);
    self.mmProductList = ko.observableArray(['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4']);
    self.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
    self.prodAllocation = ko.observable();

    self.products = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(products, function(contact) {
        return { prodName: contact.prodName, splits: ko.observableArray(contact.splits) };
    }));

    self.addProduct = function() {
        currentProduct = self.selectedProduct();
        self.products.push({
            prodName: currentProduct,
            splits: ko.observableArray()
        });
        self.mmProductList.remove(currentProduct);
    };

    self.removeProduct = function(contact) {
        self.products.remove(contact);
        self.mmProductList.push(currentProduct);
    };

    self.addDefinition = function(contact) {
        contact.splits.push({
            page: self.mmAllPages(),
            allocation: self.prodAllocation(),
        });
    };

    self.removeDefinition = function(phone) {
        $.each(self.products(), function() { this.splits.remove(phone) })
    };

    self.productPercent = function(products){
    };
```

Right now when I set the value of the allocation field to the prodAllocation observable, all of the subsequent allocation fields are updated with that value. I'm not sure how to make these fields independently observable.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. could you pout in brackects the label after the variable if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand where you are trying to go, there are several problems with your code:

1. You bind to `$root.prodAllocation` instead of `allocation`
2. You do not update `$root.prodAllocation`

For 2., you can replace your addDefinition with this:

```
    self.addDefinition = function(contact) {
        var s = {
            page: self.mmAllPages(),
            allocation: ko.observable(),
        };
        s.allocation.subscribe(function () { 
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < contact.splits().length; i++)
                sum += contact.splits()[i].allocation() *1;
            self.prodAllocation(sum);
        });
        contact.splits.push(s);            
    };
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/NRZXE/

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only thing I changed was adding parseInt() around the sum calculation - because for the first observable value it was returning NaN.

Comment: I know, I'm the worst. I do have one more question though. When I access prodAllocation using $root.prodAllocation it outputs the summed values perfectly, however, when you add a new product the value is not independent. Is there another way of accessing that variable that will output the values independtly? I've update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e984J/2/

Comment: What do you mean "the value is not independant"?

Comment: The value of prodAllocation is not tied to the products individually. So when you add a second product, the prodAllocation value from the first product is already populated in the second product.

Comment: You mean to say there should be one prodAllocation for each product? If so you should move it to `products` instead of `root`